# How to detect dips with pandas or numpy array when data has repetitions?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to find the position of dips and bumps in an array by checking that `n < n-1` and `n > n+1`.

It is a valid approach, but it fails when data repeats before bouncing, e.g. `{100,80,80,100}`.

See this example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([100,250,200,350,650,650,650,500,400,300,300,350,100])

dips = np.flatnonzero((np.roll(data,1) > data).astype(int) & (data < np.roll(data,-1)).astype(int))
bumps = np.flatnonzero((np.roll(data,1) < data).astype(int) & (data > np.roll(data,-1)).astype(int))

print(dips,bumps)
```

I could make it work by removing the repetitive elements, so we get more output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':data})
data = (df.loc[df.shift(-1)['close'] != df['close']]).to_numpy()

dips = np.flatnonzero((np.roll(data,1) > data).astype(int) & (data < np.roll(data,-1)).astype(int))
bumps = np.flatnonzero((np.roll(data,1) < data).astype(int) & (data > np.roll(data,-1)).astype(int))

print(dips,bumps)
```

However, clearly in this case the order will not be preserved, hence the result is invalid.

I don't know it seems like an easy problem but I can't quite solve it yet without falling back to `i, j` loops.

**Edit**: the expected output should capture all dips and bumps in a correct order:

```
dips:  [2,9] or [2,10]
bumps: [1,4,11] or [1,5,11] or [1,6,11]
```

Since values are same in there we could use first, middle or last position.

[image]

Comment: kindly share the expected output array

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
dips, bumps = find_peaks(-data), find_peaks(data)
```